# Interesting results with Java switch statement and enums

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, case

Whilst debugging my code, I came across this interesting scenario with my switch statement on an enumeration.

To me it looks like it should not compile and prevented me from making the silly mistake, is there something I am missing where this syntax can be used?

My java version is 1.6.0_10

```
private enum E_TEST
{
    A, B, C, D, E
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    for( E_TEST e : E_TEST.values() )
    {
        switch( e )
        {
            case A: B: C: D: E:
            {
                System.out.println( e );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, the output of this code is as follows.

```
A
```

Comment: What made you think, this code fails, is it switch part (or) case part? and I strongly suspect your java is version 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

Comment: My expected output was A B C D E, to get my expected result in needed the keyword case in front of all the enums.

I expected the compiler to pick up this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code compiles because in the line

```
        case A: B: C: D: E:
```

the B:, C:, D: and E: are labels.

It doesn't do what you expect because that line should be

```
case A: case B: case C: case D: case E:
```

as dasblinkenlight noted in his post.